# spring запрос mongodb

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mongodb, aggregate

есть коллекция из этого надо сгруппировать документы по часам
в монго запрос выглядит следующим образом:

```
db.user_action.aggregate([
// Get only records created in a time span
{$match: {createdDate: {$gte: ISODate("2022-01-01T00:00:00Z"), $lte: ISODate("2022-01-10T00:00:00Z")}}},
// Get the year, month and day from the createdTimeStamp
{
    $project: {
        "year": {$year: "$createdDate"},
        "month": {$month: "$createdDate"},
        "day": {$dayOfMonth: "$createdDate"},
        "hour": {$hour: "$createdDate"}
    }
},
// Group by year, month, day and hour and get the count
{
    $group: {
        _id: {
            year: "$year",
            month: "$month",
            day: "$day",
            hour: "$hour"
        },
        "count": {
            $sum: 1
        }
    }
}
])
```

запрос работает корректно но как писать такой запрос в java?
пока делал так но работает не корректно

```
MatchOperation filterStates = match(new Criteria("createdDate")
    .gte(t1).lte(t2));

ProjectionOperation projectionOperation = project("createdDate", "year").and("createdDate").as("year")
    .andExpression("createdDate").as("year")
    .andExpression("createdDate").as("month")
    .andExpression("createdDate").as("day")
    .andExpression("createdDate").as("hour");

GroupOperation groupByUserAndSumUserId = Aggregation.group("year", "month", "day", "hour").count().as("sum");

Aggregation aggregation
    = newAggregation(filterStates, projectionOperation, groupByUserAndSumUserId);

return reactiveMongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "user_action", String.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

как минимум нашел два варианта:
первый вариант:

```
MatchOperation filterStates = match(new Criteria("createdDate")
        .gte(t1).lte(t2));

ProjectionOperation projectionOperation = project()
        .and(DateOperators.Year.yearOf("createdDate")).as("year")
        .and(DateOperators.Month.monthOf("createdDate")).as("month")
        .and(DateOperators.DayOfMonth.dayOfMonth("createdDate")).as("day")
        .and(DateOperators.Hour.hourOf("createdDate")).as("hour");

GroupOperation groupByUserAndSumUserId = Aggregation.group("year", "month", "day", "hour").count().as("count");

Aggregation aggregation
        = newAggregation(filterStates, projectionOperation, groupByUserAndSumUserId);

return reactiveMongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "user_action", UserActionPerHour.class);
```

и второй вариант:

```
MatchOperation filterStates = match(new Criteria("createdDate")
                .gte(t1).lte(t2));

        ProjectionOperation projectionOperation = project()
                .and("createdDate").dateAsFormattedString("%Y-%m-%d %H").as("yearMonthDayUTC");

        GroupOperation groupByUserAndSumUserId = Aggregation.group("yearMonthDayUTC").count().as("count");

        Aggregation aggregation
                = newAggregation(filterStates, projectionOperation, groupByUserAndSumUserId);

        return reactiveMongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "user_action", UserActionPerHour.class);
```